# Why file attachment has different URLs in icons links and default link on node page?

Tags: 7, files

I have node with attached file. Node attachments view look:

[image]

`sample.pdf` link has url like `sites/default/files/sample.pdf`. I can download file via this link.

Links with icons has URL like `download/file/fid/[id]`

I can't download some of files via icon links (403).

How can I change this behaviour? I want those links point to `sites/default/files/sample.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there can be custom or some contributed module doing the trick.
The menu - download/file/fid/[id] is created by some module and allowing you to download the file.
Might be a case that the logic is written in the same callback.

try searching your modules with this callback and you might see some results...